# Program visible to Linux as normal directory

Tags: c, linux, directory, filesystems

I'm trying to write program to work as programmable directory, in other words: User, or other systems open that directory and read/write files or dirs. I try to create program to cache most used files in memory (less I/O to HDD), but right now I don't know how to achive that. There are probably some docs about this but I can't find them. I know that there is FUSE, NFS and others, but reading their source is quite difficult. If any one has info about implementation in C lang I'll be very grateful.

Sorry for my English..

Comment: Duplicate - same user - yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553715

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553715/program-as-directory-in-linux

Comment: You are aware that Linux already _does exactly what you describe_, by default?

Answer (score 1):

FUSE has a C interface - take a look at their [Hello World example](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/helloworld.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple implementation, try Python's FUSE library. A quick tutorial can be found [here](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/fuse/index.php?title=FUSE_Python_tutorial).

Comment: I agree FUSE is the way to proceed because what you are describing is creating your own type of file system.

Comment: But I need to create a compiled program so every python, ruby parts of code is not a solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at the [GIO library](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gio/stable/) — it's part of GTK, but can be used separately. The documentation is pretty thorough, and if you need to do some quick prototyping you can use the [PyGTK GIO bindings](http://library.gnome.org/devel/pygobject/stable/gio-class-reference.html) to mess around before going back and writing it in C.

It's licensed under the LGPL.

Answer (score 0):

If you find it easier to code in Python, it's possible to create a compiled program using [cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/).